# how to take property value using droptarget?

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am creating a plugin and i need to know the value of porosity of reservoir. If these properties exist somewhere it would be much easier if I could just access them.
So how can we take these value using "drop target button" ?

Answer (score 1):

You must subscribe to the DropTarget.DragDrop event.  The following callback method shows you how to get the object dropped on the DropTarget button.

```
void DropTarget_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Property property = e.Data.GetData(typeof(object)) as Property;
    if (property == null)
        return;

    // Do something with property, like show it in a
    // PresentationBox or store it for use later.
}
```

Comment: What class should i use for accessing value of original gas in place(OGIP) ?